# Post to WebLogic Queue from .NET

Tags: .net, jms

I need to post to WebLogic Queue from a .NET/C# web application.

Any help on how to do that is appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you gone through the documentation / tutorials?  Here is some information on that: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/jms/intro.html#wp1058350

Otherwise, if you've already made some attempts and run into trouble, please post what you tried, and what the trouble was.

Good luck.